# is.constant() function in auto.arima() R

Tags: r

In R, while viewing the source code of `auto.arima()` I noticed a function called `is.constant()`.

What is the functionality of that function? I saw the same function in `ndiffs()` also. Can somebody explain what is being done in that `is.constant()`?

Answer (score 4):

By typing

```
library(forecast)
forecast:::is.constant
```

you can see its code:

```
function (x)
{
    x <- as.numeric(x)
    y <- rep(x[1], length(x))
    isequal <- all.equal(c(x), y)
    return(isequal == TRUE)
}
```

Evidently it returns true when all values of its argument, when interpreted as numbers, are "nearly equal" as defined by the utility function `all.equal` (whose manual page is readily found).  Otherwise it returns false.

Note that a true value will be returned even when all elements of `x` are `NA` or when `x` is empty.

Comment: I had to type `library(forecast) forecast:::is.constant` on two separate lines, `library(forecast)`, then `forecast:::is.constant`

Comment: Sorry--the SE formatting combined the lines, which were separate in the original.  I'll fix that.